# Не запускается JARник через cmd

Tags: java, maven, jar

[image: pom главного модуля]

Хотел собрать запускаемый fat jar файл приложения, который будет запускаться через cmd. Создается jar, но при запуске через cmd выводит

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.App.`

В чем загвоздка?

Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался!

Comment: Команду , которой запускаете ?

Comment: @Gin java -jar homework_02-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: где-то я этот вопрос уже видел....

Comment: @michael вопрос в другом, но это продолжение(

Comment: разве тебе не говорили, что текст надо оформлять, а не картинками вставлять?

Comment: так то не говорили, весь пом текстом?

Comment: да, картинок больше ни у кого нет

Comment: понял, принял, не знал(

Comment: Пакет у класса App точно com?

Comment: Да, точно com.App